# Minizinc: output continuously values of a decision variable set of int

Tags: set, output, minizinc

i have an mzn file, that decides for the values of a set of int

```
var set of int : ids; 

output ["ids:" ++show(ids)]
```

the output though for example comes as:

> ids: 4..7

is it possible to get something like

> ids: 4,5,6,7

the continuous values of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using the `join` builtin and a comprehension to turn the set into an array of strings:

```
var set of int: ids;
...
output["ids: " ++ join(",", [ "\(i)" | i in fix(ids)] )];
```

Which will output: `ids: 1,2,3,4`

Comment: thank you, I had a look at the builtin function join as well, very helpful for this!